# 20.04 LTS - Can't log in after Nvidia driver install, from recovery mode "resume boot" works flawlessly

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04

I am using Nvidia GTX 960 2GB

I upgraded from 20.04 LTS beta to 20.04 LTS release.

After my upgrade I decided to install latest drivers for my Nvidia card so I installed:
nvidia-driver-440

After reset it won't let me log into the system, but when I start in recovery mode with normal GUI interface it works flawlessly without any issues such as screen tearing or audio not working (which I had experienced before)

What can I do to fix this?

SOLUTION: Disabling automatic logon fixed this issue.